# CSS transition from `display: none` on class change?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've started using transitions to "modernise" the feel of a site. So far, `:hover` transitions are working great. Now I'm wondering if it's possible to trigger a transition based on other things, such as when a class changes.

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
#myelem {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in, display 0.4s step-end;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in, display 0.4s step-end;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in, display 0.4s step-end;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in, display 0.4s step-end;
}
#myelem.show {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out, display 0.4s step-start;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out, display 0.4s step-start;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out, display 0.4s step-start;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out, display 0.4s step-start;
}
```

The JavaScript to trigger the change is:

```
document.getElementById('myelem').className = "show";
```

But the transition doesn't seem to be happening - it's just jumping from one state to the other.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the `-ms-` prefix on `transition` is unnecessary; Internet Explorer 10 supports `transition` unprefixed, and Internet Explorer 9 does not support transitions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't realise IE10 supported the unprefixed name.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It does work when you remove the `display` properties.

```
#myelem {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
}
#myelem.show {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
}​
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ks8jD/)**.

The reason for this is that only CSS properties with numbers can be transitioned. What do you think the "50% state" should be between "`display: none;`" and "`display: block;`"? Since that can't be calculated, you can't animate the `display` property.

Comment: Could you backup your comment some more @BoltClock ? Looking at [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css), all the  specified values have something to do with numbers (color, percentage, length, font-weight etc.) .

Comment: The word "number" is pretty vague, making that phrasing seem a little confusing. That said, one property that can be transitioned that doesn't use numeric values is `visibility`, although this doesn't result in an animated effect of course.

Comment: I figured that using `step-start` and `step-end` would be okay, since there are no intermediary values. Fair enough then.

Comment: A value that doesn't use numbers that can be transitioned are color and gradient values. For color values you can use words and the like.

Comment: I dont understand the logic behind this. I am not even defining `display` as a value of the `transition` property. Still, it only works when I have no `display` property in the css block. Why?

Comment: You don't need to apply transition properties in class "show".                  #myelem {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
}
#myelem.show {
    opacity: 1;
}

Comment: As @SofiaFerreira stated, the transition on `show` class isn't doing anything and should be removed from the answer.  See this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4cgLa5pn/).

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use the `display` property for transitioning between states.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by @MarcoK including the comments shows already the right direction. Setting `display` property *hinders* `transition`. 
A *better practice* is though to put the unprefixed (standards) version after the browser-vendor prefixed ones, in order to be future-proof. The latter properties overwrite the former.
Other improvements:

- As @Charmander pointed out, `-ms-transition` isn't supported by any Internet Explorer
- There's also Opera's vendor prefixed `-o-transition` for [Op 10.5-12 & Op Mobile 10-12](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition), which currently is probably supported by less than .1% of global browser. I'll put it in for completion

CSS:

```
#myelem {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in;
       -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-in;
         -o-transition: opacity .4s ease-in;
            transition: opacity .4s ease-in;
}
#myelem.show {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
         -o-transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
            transition: opacity .4s ease-out;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to animate show and hide elements in css, just instead of:

```
display: none;

/* and */

display: block;
```

use:

```
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 0;

/* and */

max-height: 9999999px;
```

Since you replace this properties, you are able to animate any css value with `transition`.

working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/utyja8qx/