# How can I fluidly resize my header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an  element on a page I'm building that has a JQuery function that re-sizes it when clicked.  When it is re-sized, the rest of the page follows relatively fluidly (though I haven't yet fixed it for smaller view-ports so the fiddle looks a little wonky, but you'll see what I mean), and the proportions stay true.  That is, except for the header element I have, which is:

```
<header class="pageHeader">Welcome!</header>
```

When the rest of the page re-sizes, the header jumps to a smaller width and then to the correct width.

I think this is because I gave it a negative margin of -6% on the right and left.  Here is the CSS for the header element, and the JQuery for the animation:

CSS:

```
.pageHeader
{
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 3.75%;
    padding: 1.25%;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2.25em;
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -6%;
    margin-right: -6%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menuButton").click(function(){
      if($('#sideContent').hasClass('hide')) {
        $('#sideContent').animate({width:'15%'},400).removeClass('hide');
        $('nav').animate({display:'inline-block', opacity:1},400).removeClass('hide');
        $('#pageSize').animate({width:'77%', marginLeft: '18%'},400).removeClass('big').addClass('small');
      } else { 
        $('#sideContent').animate({width:'5em'},400).addClass('hide');
        $('nav').animate({opacity:0},200).addClass('hide');
        $('#pageSize').animate({width: '87%', marginLeft: '8%'},400).removeClass('small').addClass('big');
        }
    });
});
```

How can I go about fixing this?  Should I restructure the HTML so I don't need the negative margins, or should I try to fix it through JQuery?

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/buLW8/

Comment: Restructure HTML so you can make the script simpler. Or just use css animation and js to toggle classes.

Comment: Don't do all that hardcoded animation stuff within the JS.  Instead, consider using CSS Transitions and using JS to change the element's class.  See: [CSS transition on class change?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13667827/691711) I think the CSS Transition stuff also has better performance than animating through interpolated JS as well.

Comment: @zero298 out of curiosity, why is it better to animate with CSS than with JS/JQuery

Comment: @metsales Mostly, it's because this is mostly a layout change. Layout should be relegated to CSS.  You write meaningful markup in the HTML, you write functionality in JS, and do your layout in CSS.  Would you prefer to have to change all those values by hand in JS and then rerun your page after the edit?  You can almost change them on the fly through the CSS file in most IDE's.  I also believe that you get better performance through CSS.  However, some like to debate this [CSS Anim](http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/)

Comment: Okay, awesome.  I make the suggestions you guys proposed.  Now my JS is only changing the classes of the elements, and the animations works very well and is much more fluid.  Than you all for the help!  here's the updated fiddle if anyone might be interested, or has any more input. http://jsfiddle.net/buLW8/1/