# CSS transition on child element where parent toggles display property

Tags: html, css

I read this: [SO css-transition-from-display-none-on-class-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667827/css-transition-from-display-none-on-class-change) but I'm trying to toggle the display property on parent element. Is there a workaround to make it work?

CSS transition works like so
[fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v1aym7wd/](https://jsfiddle.net/v1aym7wd/)

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    /*display: none;*/
}

#wrap.show {
    /*display: block;*/
}

.fade {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity 10s;
}

#wrap.show .fade {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
wrap.classList.add('show');
```

But as soon as I toggle `display:block/none` on parent element the CSS transition does not work. Why is this? Any way to make it work?

[See here: https://jsfiddle.net/v1aym7wd/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/v1aym7wd/1/)

Comment: when you put `display: none` for parent, the child is also not displayed on the screen... So I guess the transition would not work...

Comment: If you can use visibility instead of display, it should work. (If you can’t have the effect of visibility:hidden that it reserves the space the element needs, then try combining it with width/height 0 and overflow set to hidden.)

Comment: ... Or drop transitions. Use animations. Write keyframes based on opacity. and add them to your child element. With the same `10s` duration. Just remember to set fill mode as `forwards`

Comment: @CBroe I need to use the `display` property. I can not change to `visibility`

Comment: @AnkithAmtange can you please provide an example?

Comment: Sure thing. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1aym7wd/3/). I don't have an answer to why display is not transition-able. So I'm not gonna add this below. I've set a timeout just so you know it kicks in whenever display changes.

Comment: Oooh thank you @AnkithAmtange ! You better add it below, I'll upvote and accept! Even we don't know why, it answers the question with a working solution.

Comment: Also works if you use two classes, one on the wrapper and one on the fade element, and add them separately: https://jsfiddle.net/v1aym7wd/5/

Comment: That would probably support more browsers. Than the animation method.

Comment: _“Even we don't know why”_ – we do, what @kukkuz mentioned in the very first comment is the reason. Browsers do not render elements with display:none, or any of their children – they behave as if they were not even part of the DOM tree, as far as rendering is concerned. Therefor, your fade element does not have an initial value set for opacity. And when #wrap gets the `show` class added, it gets the opacity value 1 _immediately_ - so there is nothing to transition from in this case.

Comment: @CBroe that makes sense now! (kukkuz sayd it but he was "only" guessing) Thank you, your comment should be an answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since `display:none` on a parent also takes out descendants from the DOM tree, one solution could be to drop transitions and use animations instead.

The animation will kick in when the child element is displayed.

Do use the necessary vendor prefixes.

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0.2
}

#wrap.show .fade {
  animation: reveal 10s forwards;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```js
/* set timeout to show how animation starts. */

setTimeout(function reveal() {
  var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
  wrap.classList.add('show');
}, 2000);
```

```css
#wrap {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}

#wrap.show {
  display: block
}

.fade {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.2
}

#wrap.show .fade {
  animation: reveal 10s forwards;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why have I never thought of that! What a great solution to an old problem.

Answer (score 5):

As CBroe said, it can be done by using visibility instead of display.

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanoconr/v1aym7wd/2/

```js
var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');

wrap.classList.add('show');
```

```css
#wrap {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#wrap.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.fade {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity 10s;
}

#wrap.show .fade {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
```

The code doesn't seem to work in the snippet but it is working on JSFiddle

Comment: I wasn't fast enough to check all comments and answers, unfortunately I can not change from `display` property to `visible`

Comment: If you're not able to change from display to visibility, then the only thing I can think of at the minute would be to also use change the opacity on the parent as well as display.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help: Ankith got a working solution for me above in the comments: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611225/css-transition-on-child-element-where-parent-toggles-display-property?noredirect=1#comment66531633_39611225)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
    wrap.classList.add('show');
  },1000);
```

```css
#wrap {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
}

#wrap.show {
   opacity: 1;
}

.fade {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity 10s;
}

#wrap.show .fade {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no difference from the first example I've created above (https://jsfiddle.net/v1aym7wd/) except the `setTimeOut` and the removal of the comments. So no changes which would help.